# tinymce 5 fire error if insert newline after html element

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

i try to use the html select element (`<select size="1"><option>One</option></select>`) in my tinymce editor.

It works but if i try to insert a newline after the select element with the enter key, i get an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of null
```

[Here is an example with jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zjka8px/8/)

Why tinymce fire this error and how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE does not support "live" form elements inside of the editor. If you want to add insert them as part of some sort of form builder for a front end you should make - in this case - the ` noneditable. [See documentation for noneditable plugin here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/noneditable/)